# Nim SDL2 no window appears

Tags: sdl, nim-lang

I'm trying to follow [this](https://hookrace.net/blog/writing-a-2d-platform-game-in-nim-with-sdl2/) blog post about using SDL2 with Nim.

I've set up a project with SDL2. Using `nimble build` or `nimble run` throws no errors. When the program is running no window appears.

Similar questions in C++ have a `SDL_WINDOW_HIDDEN` flag which is not included in this example.

```
let window = createWindow(title = "Our own 2D platformer",
    x = SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, y = SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
    w = 1280, h = 720, flags = SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN)
```

I tried a few different flags.`SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS` or `SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN` but still no window appears.

Using

- MacOS Ventura 13.3.1
- Nim 1.4.8

Full program

```
import sdl2

type SDLException = object of Exception

template sdlFailIf(cond: typed, reason: string) =
  if cond: raise SDLException.newException(
    reason & ", SDL error: " & $getError())

proc main =
  sdlFailIf(not sdl2.init(INIT_VIDEO or INIT_TIMER or INIT_EVENTS)):
    "SDL2 initialization failed"

  # defer blocks get called at the end of the procedure, even if an
  # exception has been thrown
  defer: sdl2.quit()

  sdlFailIf(not setHint("SDL_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY", "2")):
    "Linear texture filtering could not be enabled"

  let window = createWindow(title = "Our own 2D platformer",
    x = SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, y = SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
    w = 1280, h = 720, flags = SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN)
  sdlFailIf window.isNil: "Window could not be created"
  defer: window.destroy()

  let renderer = window.createRenderer(index = -1,
    flags = Renderer_Accelerated or Renderer_PresentVsync)
  sdlFailIf renderer.isNil: "Renderer could not be created"
  defer: renderer.destroy()

  # Set the default color to use for drawing
  renderer.setDrawColor(r = 110, g = 132, b = 174)

  # Game loop, draws each frame
  while true:
    # Draw over all drawings of the last frame with the default
    # color
    renderer.clear()
    # Show the result on screen
    renderer.present()

main()
```

Nimble dependancies

```
# Dependencies
requires "nim >= 1.4.8"
requires "sdl2"
```